# How to get multiple elements values

Tags: dart

How do I get the values from multiple inputs with Dart?
I'm trying this way...

```dart
void main() {
    List<InputElement> inputs = queryAll('input');
    FormElement form = query('#compra');

    form.onSubmit.listen( (e) {
        for (InputElement input in inputs) {
            String aux = inputs[input].value;
            print(aux);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok. And what were your results?

Comment: Breaking on exception: type 'InputElement' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is currently passing an InputElement as an index of a List of InputElement's. Since you are already iterating over each input you can just do this:

```dart
void main() {
    List<InputElement> inputs = queryAll('input');
    FormElement form = query('#compra');

    form.onSubmit.listen( (e) {
        for (InputElement input in inputs) {
            String aux = input.value;
            print(aux);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please mark as accepted if you feel I've adequately addressed your question with enough information :)